# android app published but not visible in google play

Tags: android, google-play

I developed and publish some apps to google play using "old" interface. Now I published an app using new interface and seems that all were successful because my app appears as "published". However, previous apps were active in 1h, but now, after 2 days, I am unable to find it in google play and also unable to find any link on any option inside developer console. Is my app published? How could I then know google play link?

[image]

Comment: can you drop your app link if possible ?

Comment: Go to the Google Play from the Any Desktop or any Laptop Browser then search app from the exact package name of your application

Comment: ok, could be basic but didn't know link format. So, my app is now available at https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=es.visiononline.stockpro , when will it be indexed using google play search??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How could I then know google play link?

The links for Apps in the Playstore are always built with the same pattern, it looks like this:
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=YOUR.PACKAGE.NAME

so you can use that link to see if your App is published or not, just replace YOUR.PACKAGE.NAME with the actual name of the package like com.google.android.music

Comment: great, so my app is available!! Probably will need fews days more to be indexed using google play search?

Answer (score 0):

In the new interface you can publish three versions of the app: alpha, beta, release. Check if you published the release version.
So you'll get the link to the app: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=COM.PACKAGE.NAME

Answer (score -1):

1. Check your publish area
2. Check your Android version
3. Check your Android device